# .htaccess: Hide existing files but use them through RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried this several ways, read a lot of examples and questions here and still can't figure out if it can't be done at all.
What I want is to force access to certain files and functions using a certain URL format and deny access (fake 404) to everything else - even existing files/directories.

This part works:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([\w]+)$ /somefolder/index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^person/([\d]+) /somefolder/index.php?page=person&id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^css/([\w]+\.css) /somefolder/css/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^images/([\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}/[\d]+\.(gif|jpe?g)) /somefolder/images/$1 [NC,L]
```

The following line, however, causes a 500 internal server error:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /somefolder/index.php?page=error [R=404]
```

I want that if /somefolder/index.php (or any other file/directory that may or may not exist) is requested by the visitor, it should return 404 and the error page. I also plan on adding this later:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /somefolder/index.php?page=error
```

The .htaccess file is in the root. Is this doable at all?

Examples:

(pages accessed by users and linked to by other pages)
http://example.com/breakfast -> http://example.com/somefolder/index.php?page=breakfast
(stylesheets used by the pages)
http://example.com/css/default.css -> http://example.com/somefolder/css/default.css
(images used in the documents)
http://example.com/images/2011-01-01/test.jpg -> http://example.com/somefolder/images/2011-01-01/test.jpg
(everything else)
http://example.com/this/may.exist -> 404 + error page

.. which would mean that if someone attempts to get http://example.com/somefolder/css/default.css (exists), they wouldn't receive it.

Comment: ¿How exactly is the `certain URL format`? If possible with a description that highlights the differences with the rest of URLs, specifying which segments are fixed strings and which are variable? That information is important to better understand what you want.

Comment: One of the "format" parts would be that pages must be accessed by using the page name after the domain part, like http://example.com/thispage - requesting the real file should result in an error (missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what I wanted; it denies direct access to all php files but allows them to run through shortcuts:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?page=error
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?page=error

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?page=start [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]

<Files ".ht*">
    Order Allow,Deny
</Files>

<Files "*.php">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from env=REDIRECT_STATUS
</Files>
```

This causes a 500 error because (I think) it creates an infinite loop - every time a rewrite occurs, the htaccess files are processed once more:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /somefolder/index.php?page=error [R=404]
```